# Web socket (raspberry pi) not sending message

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, raspberry-pi

Hi so I have a raspberry pi that I'm working with that I want to connect to over a webpage, to do this I have a WebSocket connection setup so that I can send input from a html page to the raspberry pi. Here is the code in my javascript file:

```
function sendData()
   { 
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
           alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

           // Let us open a web socket
           var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9998/echo");

           ws.onopen = function() 
          {    
              // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
              ws.send("Message to send");
              alert("Message is sent...");
           };

           ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
           { 
              var received_msg = evt.data;
              alert("Message is received...");
           };

           ws.onclose = function() 
           {    
              // websocket is closed.
              alert("Connection is closed..."); 
           };
        } 
   else {       
           // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
           alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }


  }
```

When I run the program though, it won't send the message, "message to send" and I either get a WebSocketException: Handshake Status 200 or a Connection timeout error. I know the raspberry pi connects to the website because it gets information about my browser. But the ws.open won't open and send the message.

Comment: What sort of WebSocket server are you running on the RPi?

Comment: Just a normal python WebSocket server.